# Unit testing a method that returns the smallest value of an array

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have kind of a theoretical question. Given a method:

```
public int findSmallestArrayValue(int[] values){

    int smallest = values[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < values.length; count++){

        if(values[count] < smallest){
            smallest = values[count];
        }
    }

    return smallest;
}
```

What would you potentially unit test here ? So far I have come up with:

```
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5,11,3,6,8}),3);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5,5,5,5,5}),5);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{-1,2,3,4,5}),-1);
```

Now I ask myself, what else would be useful/possible ? For example I came up with:

- values that are larger than int, but Java won't let me do that ?
- empty array, how to do that ?
- filling up the int array with more values than int can take ?

Especially what is actually useful and what is not ? What do you think ?

Comment: For empty array, you can use `new int[0]`. I would also test null possibility.

Comment: You do not handle properly the empty array (or the `null` one): it throws an exception. Bear in mind that you cannot test everything, so, you should test a few normal cases, and the limit ones (empty array eg). However, over-testing your code brings more harm than good, especially for straight-forward functions

Comment: What do you mean like:                 assertNull(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{})); ?

Comment: Interview question, right?

Comment: Yes. But the interview is over, I was just curious how to do this in general ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current test ideas are good so far. Here's the additional tests I would consider adding

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void emptyArrayIsNotAcceptedArgument() {
    array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{});
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void nullArrayIsNotAcceptedArgument() {
    array.findSmallestArrayValue(null);
}

@Test
public void lastValueIsSmallest() {
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{0,-1}),-1);
}
```

As for your ideas:

- values that are larger than int, but Java won't let me do that ?

  - Java's compiler will not allow you to pass in anything but an int[] to that method, so no test needed
- filling up the int array with more values than int can take ?

  - Java arrays cannot have a size larger than the max int value. This wouldn't really add much benefit to your tests anyways.

Comment: Hi, the compiler tells me that it should be ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and NullPointerException, tried it with those and it works...

Comment: Sure... But what I'm suggesting is that you modify your method to throw an IllegalArgumentException in those cases. The exceptions being thrown with your current implementation aren't really appropriate for the input.

Comment: Hmm, like:        `if (values == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array is null");
        } else if (values.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array is empty");
        }` ? I still get NullPointerException ...

Comment: I was stupid, setting the array 0 and then jumping to if/else ;-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply in time. Yes, the issue was that you were using the array before checking if it was null. Always check the most important preconditions first :).

Answer (score 0):

Some cases that come to mind:

- (Your suggestion) Check for empty array

  - `values.length > 0`
- Check for null array

  - `values != null`

These would be cases you would handle within the method, and ensure that the method outputs the correct error message or Exception that you write in.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to test boundary conditions.  So you will want to test:

- Null
- Empty
- One
- Several
- All negatives
- Mix of positives and negatives

You had some of those and others have provided the others.  Keep in mind that having a test like this:

```
assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5,11,3,6,8}),3);
```

makes having a test like this of very little value:

```
assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5,11,6,8}),5);
```

Now when you do encounter a defect in a method, you will want to write a test that exposes the conditions of that defect.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! Thank you for the answers, I appreciate it! I think a good mix is key here:

```
public class ArrayValuesTest {

ArrayValues array = new ArrayValues();

@Test
public void returnsSmallestValue() {

    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5,11,3,6,8}),3);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{5}),5);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{0}),0);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{-5,-8,-3,-6,-11}),-11);
    assertEquals(array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{-20,11,-3,6,-8}),-20);

}

@Test(expected = ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
public void emptyArrayIsNotAcceptedArgument() {
    array.findSmallestArrayValue(new int[]{});
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void nullArrayIsNotAcceptedArgument() {
    array.findSmallestArrayValue(null);
}
```

}

Do you think it's bad practice to include several asserts in the first test method instead of having separate test methods ?